# Seperate values in specific dataframe column to some row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with multivalue in some columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','3',],
                   'fruits': ['apple, Apple','Orange, grapefruit','Melon'],
                   'count': [2,2,1]})
```

I want to seperate the value in fruits column, so my dataframe become like this

```
id  fruits
 1  apple
 1  Apple
 2  Orange
 2  grapefruit
 3  Melon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [reassign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the column values by [splitting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) comma separated strings and [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) results.

```py
df = df.assign(fruits=df['fruits'].str.split(',')).explode('fruits')
```

Output will be:

```
  id       fruits  count
0  1        apple      2
0  1        Apple      2
1  2       Orange      2
1  2   grapefruit      2
2  3        Melon      1
```

---

If you want you can reorder the index, without duplicates, just do a [reset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```py
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output will be:

```
  id       fruits  count
0  1        apple      2
1  1        Apple      2
2  2       Orange      2
3  2   grapefruit      2
4  3        Melon      1
```

Comment: Than you v'much

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `str` methods with `explode` on the relevant columns:

```
ser = df.fruits.str.split(",\s").explode()
```

output:

```
0         apple
0         Apple
1        Orange
1    grapefruit
2         Melon
Name: fruits, dtype: object
```

if you wish to keep the `id`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(ser)
df2['id'] = df['id']
```

this uses the index of df, df2 to insert the value of `id`:

```
       fruits id
0       apple  1
0       Apple  1
1      Orange  2
1  grapefruit  2
2       Melon  3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','fruits'])

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = pd.DataFrame([[row['id'],fruit.replace(" ", "")] for fruit in row['fruits'].split(',')], columns=['id','fruits'], index = [i for _ in row['fruits'].split(',')])
    df2 = df2.append(temp)
```

This answer is slower than the previous answers since it doesn’t use Pandas built-in functions (assign or explode) but is easier to understand algorithmically.

Comment: hm, I really recommend using the built-in functionality when possible. When this is scaled to 10k+ rows, you will definitely notice a difference! After some time the build-ins become more familiar